# nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet

Tags: denial-of-service

I see a lot of these messages in /var/log/messages of my Linux server

```
kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
kernel: __ratelimit: 15812 callbacks suppresse
```

while my server is under DoS attack but the memory is not still saturated. I am wondering what is the significance of the message and how to counter possible security implications.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The message means your connection tracking table is full. There are no security implications other than DoS. You can partially mitigate this by increasing the maximum number of connections being tracked, reducing the tracking timeouts or by disabling connection tracking altogether, which is doable on server, but not on a NAT router, because the latter will cease to function.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=54000
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout=120
sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max=<more than currently set>
```

Comment: These names may be different depending on your distro and kernel.  You can discover their names by running `sysctl --names --all | grep -i conntrack`.  Remember to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` or your distro's local equivalent in order to make these settings stick!

Comment: Does this affect ufw?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great article dealing with the subject. Essentially it just means that the table that IP tables (through APF or any other solution) uses to store persistant connections is full. At the expense of memory you can increase it.

http://pc-freak.net/blog/resolving-nf_conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet-flood-message-in-dmesg-linux-kernel-log/

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest also setting your firewall rules to reject rather than drop

One temporary, fix if you need to keep your iptables NAT rules is:

```
 linux:~# sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=131072
```

I say temporary, because raising the `nf_conntrack_max` doesn't guarantee, things will get smoothly from now on. However on many not so heavily traffic loaded servers just raising the `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=131072` to a high enough value will be enough to resolve the hassle.

– Increasing the size of nf_conntrack hash-table

The Hash table hashsize value, which stores lists of conntrack-entries should be increased propertionally, whenever net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max is raised.

```
linux:~# echo 32768 > /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize
```

The rule to calculate the right value to set is:

```
hashsize = nf_conntrack_max / 4
```

– To permanently store the made changes ;a) put into /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
linux:~# echo 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 131072' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
linux:~# /sbin/sysct -p
```

b) put in `/etc/rc.local` (before the exit 0 line):

```
echo 32768 > /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize
```

Note: Be careful with this variable, according to my experience raising it to too high value (especially on XEN patched kernels) could freeze the system.
Also raising the value to a too high number can freeze a regular Linux server running on old hardware.

– For the diagnosis of `nf_conntrack` stuff there is ;

`/proc/sys/net/netfilter` kernel memory stored directory. There you can find some values dynamically stored which gives info concerning `nf_conntrack` operations in "real time":

```
linux:~# cd /proc/sys/net/netfilter linux:/proc/sys/net/netfilter# ls
-al nf_log/ total 0 dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 ./ dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 23:02 9
```

IV. Decreasing other nf_conntrack NAT time-out values to prevent server against DoS attacks

Generally, the default value for `nf_conntrack_*` time-outs are (unnecessery) large.

Therefore, for large flows of traffic even if you increase `nf_conntrack_max`, still shorty you can get a `nf_conntrack` overflow table resulting in dropping server connections. To make this not happen, check and decrease the other `nf_conntrack` timeout connection tracking values:

```
linux:~# sysctl -a | grep conntrack | grep timeout 
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120 
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events_retry_timeout = 15
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent2 = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
```

All the timeouts are in seconds. `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout` as you see is quite high – 600 secs = (10 minutes).
This kind of value means any NAT-ted connection not responding can stay hanging for 10 minutes!

The value `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000` is quite high too (5 days!)
If this values, are not lowered the server will be an easy target for anyone who would like to flood it with excessive connections, once this happens the server will quick reach even the raised up value for `net.nf_conntrack_max` and the initial connection dropping will re-occur again …

With all said, to prevent the server from malicious users, situated behind the NAT plaguing you with Denial of Service attacks:

Lower `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout` to 60 – 120 seconds and `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established` to something like 54000

```
linux:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout = 120
linux:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 54000
```

This timeout should work fine on the router without creating interruptions for regular NAT users. After changing the values and monitoring for at least few days make the changes permanent by adding them to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
linux:~# echo 'net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout = 120' >> /etc/sysctl.conf 
linux:~# echo 'net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 54000' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

according to the awesome article at 
http://pc-freak.net/blog/resolving-nf_conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet-flood-message-in-dmesg-linux-kernel-log/

Comment: Why reject rather than drop?

Comment: rejecting will send a rst instead of dropping that would keep the connection in a time wait

Comment: Thanks Sandri, yes that would be a very good reason for using reject, however TIME_WAIT is a socket state dependent on a TCP packet getting as far as the network stack. I wouldn't have expected that to happen if it is being dropped (or rejected) by the firewall (unless the forewall is letting the handshake go through then changing its mind about the connection later). I had a quick google but couldn't find anything relevant. Are you aware of any authoritative resources on reject vs drop and time_wait?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link on the web which gives an in-depth answer: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-handle-net-netfilter-nf-conntrack-count-max-exceeded/5051  Here's the relevant bits in case the link becomes stale:

Impermanent changes:

```
$ for i in close_wait fin_wait time_wait ; do sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_${i}=60 ; done
$ sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=524288
```

Revert change if it doesn't help.  You can look at /var/log/syslog for errors:

```
$ for i in close_wait fin_wait time_wait ; do sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_${i}=120 ; done
$ sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=262144
```

Make change permanent:

```
$ cat <<EOF > /etc/sysctl.conf
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 524288
EOF
```